# Webpack resolve alias with shared react components outside root

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a two projects `app1` and `app2`.

Both these projects are different npm packages.

I have a shared set of files in `shared` folder.

```
- MyComputer
|- app1
|- app2 
|- shared
```

`shared` has set of files react files only (*no `npm modules` or `package.json` or `.babelrc` etc*).

```
- shared
|- index.js
|- MyComponent
  |- MyComponent.js
  |- index.js
```

My both `webpack.config.js` inside `app1` and `app2` has

```
  const sharedModule = path.resolve(__dirname, '../shared/');
  resolve: {
     alias: {
       'shared': sharedModule,
     },
   },
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [sharedModule, path.join(__dirname, 'src')],
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
        },
      },
```

When using this config the webpack does not know what to do with files inside `shared` and thus gives errors like `unexpected token <MyComponent>` etc

Now when im copying my `shared` folder inside the root of `app1` and `app2` it compiles without any error.

i.e like this
`const sharedModule = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/shared/')`

How can i have the shared components outside the root ? because i cant maintain to copy the my `shared` folder inside `app1` and `app2` everytime i make a change in `shared` folder.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?